# InaccessibleObjectException java 17 upgrade

Tags: java, gradle, java-17

While upgrading my project to java 17, junit test cases are failing with the exception

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final long java.util.ArrayList.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @65ae6ba4
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:130)
    at org.mockito.internal.matchers.apachecommons.EqualsBuilder.reflectionAppend(EqualsBuilder.java:296)
    at org.mockito.internal.matchers.apachecommons.EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(EqualsBuilder.java:257)
    at org.mockito.internal.matchers.apachecommons.EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(EqualsBuilder.java:137)
    at org.mockito.internal.matchers.apachecommons.ReflectionEquals.matches(ReflectionEquals.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.TypeSafeMatching.apply(TypeSafeMatching.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.MatcherApplicationStrategy.forEachMatcherAndArgument(MatcherApplicationStrategy.java:84)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher.argumentsMatch(InvocationMatcher.java:156)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher.matches(InvocationMatcher.java:82)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.InvocationContainerImpl.findAnswerFor(InvocationContainerImpl.java:96)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:87)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptSuperCallable(MockMethodInterceptor.java:113)
```

in build.gradle test task is defined like this with vm agrs

--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED

--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

```
test {
    exclude 'com/corporative/**'
    maxHeapSize = "2048m"
    doFirst {
      jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.testRuntimeClasspath.find { it.name.contains("jmockit") }.absolutePath}",
              '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED',
              '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED'
    }
}
```

but test cases are still failing, if I configure these vm options in my intellij run/debug configuration it works. but not with build.gradle configuration.

Can someone help me in this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of mockito do you use? Older versions did things that are no longer allowed with Java 11 / Java 17 / Java 21. It is therefore imperative to upgrade libraries like mockito to versions that work with Java 17.

Comment: @ThomasKläger thanks for commenting, i am using  testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '3.4.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-RC.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-RC.4'

Comment: Could also be related: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2449

Comment: According to my research you should use at least version 3.5.0 of mockito-core (that version includes some changes to better support the JPMS which was introduced with Java 9). Note that the latest version of the mockito release 3 was 3.12.4, released in August 2021 and the current last version of mockito is 5.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Try each arg separately like this

```
test {
    exclude 'com/corporative/**'
    maxHeapSize = "2048m"
    doFirst {
      jvmArgs ("-javaagent:${configurations.testRuntimeClasspath.find { it.name.contains("jmockit") }.absolutePath}")
    jvmArgs("--add-opens", "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED")
    jvmArgs("--add-opens", "java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED")
    }
}
```